# Need to clear local storage using a checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox, local-storage

I understand local storage is cleared using:

```
localStorage.clear();
```

How would you use this with a checkbox? Let's say you have a checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="all" value="" name="all"> Remove All
```

I'd prefer if it's done using javascript (instead of jquery).

Thanks!

Comment: Bind event using `addEventListener` and add the code in handler

Comment: On which event you want your action to be taken ?

Comment: When do you need to trigger local storage clear? When you check the checkbox, when you submit the form?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this by using add `addEventListener` for `change` event

```
document.getElementById("all").addEventListener('change', function(){
      if(this.checked)
      {
           localStorage.clear();
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may using change event handler:

```js
var clear = function(toClear) {
  if(toClear)
    localStorage.clear();
};
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="all" value="" name="all" onchange="clear(this.checked);"/> Remove All
```